# What is the name for moments, a parameter that is calculated

Tags: regression, time-series

I am looking to correctly name something.

Often when I have my data, I calculate a "value". For instance a moment like the mean value, or a quantile. Or I aggregate a continuous variable into say 5 categories. For instance, for a time series I would calculate the mean value or some wavelet coefficients.

Then I use all those "values" as input for, e.g., my regression analysis. In quantitative trading lay people call those calculated values "signal", but that sounds strange to me.

In general, what is the name for those "values"? How would a statistician name those?

Comment: Sample statistics. A mean, a quantile, a category frequency is a statistic calculated from a sample. (Personally I am happy with statistics that are scalars, vectors, matrices or yet other objects, so that e.g. a scatter plot is also a sample statistic.)  Nothing stops those statistics being someone else's data. So, "statistics" means (a) the field (b) data in lay terms (baseball statistics, trade statistics) (c) results calculated from samples (d) the most fun you can have without laughing. Of these, (d) is the most important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for the word "statistic", which means a function of the sample. Examples of statistics include:

- the mean
- the .8 quantile
- the maximum
- the minimum and maximum as an ordered pair
- the proportion of values in the sample equal to 3

Comment: And how would I call a calculated wavelet coefficient? Would I call that also statistic or in this case something else?

Comment: @mrsteve I don't know what a wavelet coefficient is.

Comment: See the comment by @NickCox, which affirms you could indeed call a wavelet coefficient a statistic.  You don't even need to know what it is: all you really need to know about it is that it's something that can be computed for any sample and it depends only on the sample values.

Comment: Just in case someone is interested: wavelet wavelets, wavelet transformations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet are used in multivariate time series analysis, e.g., when the time series is not assumed to be stationary. The wikipedia page has a definition of coefficients.